# How to rename the 'fit.log' in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, curve-fitting, points, logfile

I was looking for a function in gnuplot to set the name of the file with the fit data. The file 'fit.log'. I know there is something about "set fit logfile 'myfit.log'" but i am not able to set the name of the file.. It always create the file fit.log.
Any ideas?

```
    f(x)=a*x+b
    fit f(x) 'data.dat' u 2:1 via a,b 
    set fit logfile 'myfit.log'
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to specify the fit output filename **before** the fit itself:

```
f(x)=a*x+b
set fit logfile 'myfit.log'
fit f(x) 'data.dat' u 2:1 via a,b
```

There are more fit parameters to set (check `help set fit`). Of course, you you have to set them all *before* the fit.

Comment: Ok thank you a lot, i´ll try this. But maybe i´ve asked the question wrong. I used gnuplot there with scripts and the terminal cairolatex. when i write  "set fit logfile 'myfit.log'" after i close the cairolatex terminal it works. Anyway i´ve got the the result that i want. 
But i´ll check yours! thank you buddy!